# postgresql select distinct latest record

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like:

```
id  fkey  srno  remark  date
1   A001  1
2   A001  2
3   A002  1
4   A003  1 
5   A002  2
```

I want distinct latest record based on max srno like

```
2  A001  2
4  A003  1
5  A002  2
```

Answer (score 11):

The best way to do this in Postgres is to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fkey) id, fkey, srno
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY fkey, srno DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

use window function `row_number()`

```
select * from (
select *,row_number() over(PARTITION by fkey order by srno desc) rn from table1 t1 
) t where rn=1
```

you can write it by using cte

```
with cte as
(
    select *,row_number() over(PARTITION by fkey order by srno desc) rn from 
    table_name t1
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename where srno in
(select max(srno) from tablename b where a.fkey=b.fkey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a subquery with an `IN` operator

```
with tab(id, fkey, srno) as 
(
 select 1,'A001',1 union all
 select 2,'A001',2 union all    
 select 3,'A002',1 union all
 select 4,'A003',1 union all    
 select 5,'A002',2   
)
select *
  from tab
 where ( fkey, srno ) in
 (
  select fkey, max(srno)
    from tab
   group by fkey
 );

id  fkey    srno
2   A001     2
4   A003     1
5   A002     2
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/KPF2258)