# PostgreSQL: Need to retrieve latest change of subscription status for every client

Tags: postgresql

I have the below table, the current subscription status of the client is "N", however, I want to retrieve the row when the client said "N" after saying "Y" previously.  It can be the other way around too, the client could've said "Y" after saying "N" previously.

Example 1:
Table and desired output - here I want third row as the client has said "N" after saying "Y".

[image]

Example 2:

Here I want the second row, as the client said "N" after "Y".

[image]

Comment: Please delete the table images and instead post text.  Also, change the ordering of the tables to reflect the actual sort order you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405954/5962802 You may also want to read the Joe Celko's book "PDF puzzles and answers"

Comment: there is no specific sorting order..

Comment: nb: there is a necessary order to determine *"previously"*. Plus it really would have been useful if you had supplied sample data in a form we could re-use (not images).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use of the LAG() function to get the previous subscription value on each row then it is possible to filter for just the wanted conditions.

```
select
    *
from (
    select 
           t.*
         , lag(subscription_status,1) over(partition by ClientID
                                           order by SubscriptionDate) as prev_ans
    from mytable as t
    ) as d
where ( subscription_status = 'N' and prev_ans = 'Y'
     OR subscription_status = 'Y' and prev_ans = 'N'
      )
```

nb: You might be able to simplify the where clause to just:

```
where subscription_status <> prev_ans
```

Comment: I guess I can tweak this logic to achieve the final outcome.. thanks Paul